# how to assign colors to positive and negative values

Tags: matlab, octave

How can I plot a map area filled with colors and colors representing the values which are negative and positive. Colormap can only give colors to values in the range [0,1]. I want to increase the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `x` be the matrix with the values you want to visualize. Then you can use [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) for a visualization:

```
x = (rand(100,100)-0.5)*10; % random values between -5 and 5

imagesc(x);
colorbar
```

Note that the colorbar is automatically adjusted to the range of date in `x`.

Comment: russia = load('russia.mat');
Z = russia.map;
[phi lambda] = meshgrid (Latitude, Longitude);
b1 = phi > 40;
b2 = phi < 80;
b = b1 & b2;
d1 = lambda > 50;
d2 = lambda < 150;
d = d1 & d2;
C = b & d;
lat_sel = phi (C);
long_sel = lambda (C);
TR4 = TR3(C);
A = ones(3861,2);
H = horzcat (TR4, A);
gratsize = [];
R = georasterref('RasterSize', size(Z), ...
    'latlim',[40 80], 'lonlim', [50 150]);
worldmap(Z,R)
meshm(Z,R);
imagesc(H);
colorbar
caxis([-0.0023 0.0017])   this is the code...here C is the interested area(lat/long) and TR4 is the interested parameter....can you help me in this?

Comment: @PrateekVerma: Pardon me, but I did not realize that you were asking about map data. Hence, my answer will not help much for your problem. I would suggest that you put your code example into your question and I will delete my answer because it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to do this:

Suppose you want to plot `x`

```
xpos=x;
xneg=x;
xpos(xpos<0)=NaN;
xneg(xneg>=0) = NaN;

plot(xpos) 
hold all;
plot(xneg)
```

Comment: it can be used to plot 2 dimensional data...but I have to plot area...it is not working for that.....